# iOS 7 presented nav controller nav bar height 64 px after frame change

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, ios7, uinavigationbar

I am presenting a UINavigationController from a UIViewController, I then want the container to move downward, hence shrinking the UINavigationController, merely to present a view at the top such as an error message, the problem is now on iOS7 the NavBar height is 64px and doesnt look right, also when I shift the UINavigationController frame back to full height and to 0 Y-origin, *sometimes* its shifting back to 44px. It seems like odd behavior. Any obvious solutions to this?

[image: shot of problem]

The black bar is the navigation bar, the gray is the UIViewController (parent)

I am also using:

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)]) {
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
    self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = NO;
}
```

Comment: Simulator -> Cmnd + 3

Comment: One of the more obvious mistakes was trying to resize a subview instead of the rootViewController in order for the navbar to not extend under the statusbar, when this was fixed throughout the app it would still resize itself under the status bar when a modal view controller was dismissed. To fix this I needed to resize the rootViewController frame again after dismissal which caused a jump effect.  I was doing this to try to keep using an error message which was implemented in <iOS7 which pushed in from the top above the navbar, I think a better approach is just to change to an updated method.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understand  your question quite clearly, but it seems to me that you should try `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeBottom;` instead of `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;`